# Is Google play caching the products purchased for offline reference?

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play, in-app-billing

Confused as to how the billing service is validating an old purchase after uninstall / reinstall, clearing app data and while the device is offline. I am using James Montemagno's Plugin.InAppBilling for Xamarin. I have a pretty simple MyProduct kind of class with this function.

The IEnumerable that is returned from GetPurchasesAsync has my test purchase in it, when the device is offline. Is this information stored in google play services offline? How do I get rid of it?

```
public async Task<bool> WasItemPurchased()
        {

            var billing = CrossInAppBilling.Current;
            try
            {
                var connected = await billing.ConnectAsync();

                if (!connected)
                {
                    //Couldn't connect
                    this.PurchYN = false;
                }

                //check purchases
                var purchases = await billing.GetPurchasesAsync(ItemType.InAppPurchase);

                //check for null just incase
                if (purchases?.Any(p => p.ProductId == this.AppProdID) ?? false)
                {
                    //Purchase restored
                    this.PurchYN = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //no purchases found
                    this.PurchYN = false;
                }
            }
            catch (InAppBillingPurchaseException purchaseEx)
            {
                //Billing Exception handle this based on the type
                Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + purchaseEx);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.PurchYN = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                await billing.DisconnectAsync();
            }

            return this.PurchYN;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you clear the cached data for the Play store it should get rid of it.